# What is wrong with this Java Puzzlers piece of code?

Tags: java, try-catch, try-catch-finally, effective-java, try-finally

In new, third edition of Effective Java Joshua Bloch mentions piece of code from Java Puzzlers (it's about closing resources in try-finally):

> For starters, I got it wrong on page 88 of Java Puzzlers, and no one noticed for years. In fact, two-thirds of the uses of the close method in the Java libraries were wrong in 2007.

But I am not sure which part is wrong here?

```
} finally {
  if (in != null) {
    try {
      in.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
      // There is nothing we can do if close fails
    }
  }
  if (out != null) {
    try {
      out.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
      // Again, there is nothing we can do if close fails
    }
  }
}
```

This is new version of this code:

```
try {
  OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dst);
  try {
    byte[] buf = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int n;
    while ((n = in.read(buf)) >= 0) out.write(buf, 0, n);

  } finally {
    out.close();
  }
} finally {
  in.close();
}
```

Comment: These days the new version is wrong too. In general, we should use `try-with-resources` instead. `try-with-resources` has more comprehensive handling when multiple exceptions are thrown. For example, in Bloch's second example, if both `in.close()` and `out.close()` throw an exception, the one thrown from `out.close()` will be lost forever, but `try-with-resources` [adds it to the suppressed exceptions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#addSuppressed-java.lang.Throwable-). https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Comment: @Radiodef Yes, try-with-resources is a recommended solution, I just wanted to make sure what was wrong in this pre try-with-resources world.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If `in.close()` throws an exception not caught by the catch block (such as any `RuntimeException`), `out` won't be even tried to be closed.

While in the given example (with normal streams where `IOException` would be most likely) it's not a huge issue, the code is not correct and learning to write it like that could cause more serious issues down the road.